# How to add own option to emerging menu windows?

Tags: java, windows

I'm using Java to create a program, the GUI is being created with Java Swing. So I'd like to know what can I do to make my program appear in the emerging menu on Windows (right-click menu).

There's a link where you can see what I mean:

[image]

So the idea is to install the program and make appear a custom option in that menu.

Comment: DYM like an 'Open With' option (a [file association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_association)) on right click?

Comment: Not that, benjamin d gave me a good resolution, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is explained here: [How can I add a context menu to the Windows Explorer for a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370114/how-can-i-add-a-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer-for-a-java-application)

Comment: Great! I didn't look for "context" menu... many thanks, but I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation.