# Huffman compressed files with my own extension

Tags: file

I am working on a project that uses Huffman algorithm to compress files, and I am doing my project using Java, what I want is to create my own file extension say (.huff) for the compressed file, and when I right click a file if it has the (.huff) extension, I want to add a new option which decompresses it, I searched the web but I did not find anything useful.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "and when I right click it I want to add a new option which decompresses it"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a context menu to the Windows Explorer for a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370114/how-can-i-add-a-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer-for-a-java-application)

Comment: @ jrtapsell I edited my question, maybe this is a better explanation

Comment: @fareed the linked question seems to be exactly what you are looking for ie. it explains how to add a right click action for a specific file extension, could you explain where it falls short?

Comment: @puhlen it does not answer my whole question just the part concerned with adding a right click action which it answers perfectly

Answer (score 0):

To set the file extension just use one of the String methods like append(".yourExtension") (append it to the filename) and set as filename. Simple as that. 
 
    String filename = filename.append(extension);

 
To decompress the compressed file, I suggest you write a metod to which you provide a path to file as argument, check if the file extension is correct and then in another method you decompress this file.

Comment: This answer does not describe how to add the custom tool to the context menu "_when I right click it I want to add a new option which decompresses it_"

Comment: You're right, but from what I understood from the question, fareed was asking about a few things. But maybe I understood wrong. _"what I want is to create my own file extension for the compressed file"_

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about a file extension, it's just a part of the file name.  To create a .huff file extension, just add .huff to the end of the file name.

To add the windows context menu, that's explained in the question linked in the comments [How can I add a context menu to the Windows Explorer for a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370114/how-can-i-add-a-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer-for-a-java-application)

I would recommend creating a batch script that will launch your program taking in the file to decompress as an argument.

Something similar to:

```
@echo off
java -cp <path-to-jar> <decompression main class> %1
```

Adding in any other setup or program arguments you need.  Then a registry entry might look like.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.huff\shell\Decompress huffman encoded file\command
"<path to batch file>" "%1"
```